# Batch check Adobe Acrobat .pdf's for files containing rotated text

Tags: pdf, text, rotation

Does anybody know if there is a way to check whether a list of Adobe Acrobat .pdf files contain rotated text (any text not at 0 degrees)?

I thought this would be simple, but I'm struggling to find an answer.

I am using ABBYY Recognition Server to OCR thousands of files and the results are quite poor where the text is rotated.  I need to get a list of files that have rotated text to allow me to perform some pre-processing on them.

I usually use iTextSharp for .pdf automation and modification but don't seem to be able to find anything for checking text rotation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your goal by extracting all words from these PDFs and checking if any of the words is rotated.

I would recommend you to use a PDF library higher level abilities for the task. [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) is a good choice (of course, I am one of the developers of the library).

Here is an articles that shows how to [extract words from PDFs](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract) with extra info about their position etc.

Each extracted word comes in `PdfTextData` object. The `PdfTextData` contains `IsTransformed` property to check if word is rotated, scaled, and / or flipped. You can also analyze `PdfTextData.TransformationMatrix` for more information about the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will take a look.  I was hoping for a 'free' way of coding my solution though.